# Ошибка при сборке gRPC. make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:4104: third_party/protobuf/CMakeFiles/libprotobuf.dir/all] Ошибка 2

Tags: c++, cmake, makefile, google-protobuf, grpc

Пытаюсь собрать gRPC C++ по [quick start gRPC](https://grpc.io/docs/languages/cpp/quickstart/) гайду.
Дошел до комманды `make -j` и на ней выскакивают ошибки, сам пытался фиксить но если честно не понимаю в чем проблема.

...

```
[ 25%] Building C object third_party/boringssl-with-bazel/CMakeFiles/crypto.dir/src/crypto/evp/p_ed25519_asn1.c.o
c++: fatal error: Убито signal terminated program cc1plus
compilation terminated.
[ 25%] Building C object third_party/boringssl-with-bazel/CMakeFiles/crypto.dir/src/crypto/thread.c.o
```

...

```
[ 31%] Building C object third_party/boringssl-with-bazel/CMakeFiles/crypto.dir/src/crypto/x509v3/pcy_map.c.o
[ 31%] Building C object third_party/boringssl-with-bazel/CMakeFiles/crypto.dir/src/crypto/x509/x_attrib.c.o
c++: fatal error: Убито signal terminated program cc1plus
compilation terminated.
c++: fatal error: Убито signal terminated program cc1plus
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [third_party/protobuf/CMakeFiles/libprotobuf.dir/build.make:566: third_party/protobuf/CMakeFiles/libprotobuf.dir/__/src/google/protobuf/descriptor.pb.cc.o] Ошибка 1
make[2]: *** Ожидание завершения заданий…
make[2]: *** [third_party/boringssl-with-bazel/CMakeFiles/ssl.dir/build.make:538: third_party/boringssl-with-bazel/CMakeFiles/ssl.dir/src/ssl/tls13_server.cc.o] Ошибка 1
make[2]: *** Ожидание завершения заданий…
make[2]: *** [third_party/boringssl-with-bazel/CMakeFiles/ssl.dir/build.make:314: third_party/boringssl-with-bazel/CMakeFiles/ssl.dir/src/ssl/ssl_cert.cc.o] Ошибка 1
c++: fatal error: Убито signal terminated program cc1plus
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [third_party/boringssl-with-bazel/CMakeFiles/ssl.dir/build.make:244: third_party/boringssl-with-bazel/CMakeFiles/ssl.dir/src/ssl/s3_lib.cc.o] Ошибка 1
[ 31%] Building C object third_party/boringssl-with-bazel/CMakeFiles/crypto.dir/src/crypto/x509v3/v3_pcons.c.o
```

...

```
[ 31%] Building C object third_party/boringssl-with-bazel/CMakeFiles/crypto.dir/src/crypto/x509v3/pcy_cache.c.o
c++: fatal error: Убито signal terminated program cc1plus
compilation terminated.
[ 31%] Building C object third_party/boringssl-with-bazel/CMakeFiles/crypto.dir/src/crypto/x509v3/v3_ia5.c.o
c++: fatal error: Убито signal terminated program cc1plus
compilation terminated.
[ 31%] Building C object third_party/boringssl-with-bazel/CMakeFiles/crypto.dir/src/crypto/x509v3/v3_pcia.c.o
[ 31%] Building C object third_party/boringssl-with-bazel/CMakeFiles/crypto.dir/src/crypto/x509v3/v3_pmaps.c.o
make[2]: *** [third_party/boringssl-with-bazel/CMakeFiles/ssl.dir/build.make:440: third_party/boringssl-with-bazel/CMakeFiles/ssl.dir/src/ssl/ssl_versions.cc.o] Ошибка 1
[ 31%] Building C object third_party/boringssl-with-bazel/CMakeFiles/crypto.dir/src/crypto/x509v3/v3_genn.c.o
make[2]: *** [third_party/boringssl-with-bazel/CMakeFiles/ssl.dir/build.make:342: third_party/boringssl-with-bazel/CMakeFiles/ssl.dir/src/ssl/ssl_file.cc.o] Ошибка 1
[ 31%] Building C object third_party/boringssl-with-bazel/CMakeFiles/crypto.dir/src/crypto/x509v3/v3_prn.c.o
c++: fatal error: Убито signal terminated program cc1plus
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [third_party/protobuf/CMakeFiles/libprotobuf-lite.dir/build.make:314: third_party/protobuf/CMakeFiles/libprotobuf-lite.dir/__/src/google/protobuf/repeated_field.cc.o] Ошибка 1
make[2]: *** Ожидание завершения заданий…
[ 32%] Building C object third_party/boringssl-with-bazel/CMakeFiles/crypto.dir/src/crypto/x509v3/v3_skey.c.o
c++: fatal error: Убито signal terminated program cc1plus
compilation terminated.
[ 32%] Building C object third_party/boringssl-with-bazel/CMakeFiles/crypto.dir/src/crypto/x509v3/pcy_node.c.o
make[2]: *** [third_party/boringssl-with-bazel/CMakeFiles/ssl.dir/build.make:258: third_party/boringssl-with-bazel/CMakeFiles/ssl.dir/src/ssl/s3_pkt.cc.o] Ошибка 1
[ 32%] Building C object third_party/boringssl-with-bazel/CMakeFiles/crypto.dir/src/crypto/poly1305/poly1305.c.o
[ 32%] Building C object third_party/boringssl-with-bazel/CMakeFiles/crypto.dir/src/crypto/x509v3/v3_lib.c.o
c++: fatal error: Убито signal terminated program cc1plus
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [third_party/boringssl-with-bazel/CMakeFiles/ssl.dir/build.make:384: third_party/boringssl-with-bazel/CMakeFiles/ssl.dir/src/ssl/ssl_privkey.cc.o] Ошибка 1
[ 32%] Building C object third_party/boringssl-with-bazel/CMakeFiles/crypto.dir/src/crypto/x509v3/v3_info.c.o
c++: fatal error: Убито signal terminated program cc1plus
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [third_party/boringssl-with-bazel/CMakeFiles/ssl.dir/build.make:132: third_party/boringssl-with-bazel/CMakeFiles/ssl.dir/src/ssl/d1_srtp.cc.o] Ошибка 1
c++: fatal error: Убито signal terminated program cc1plus
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [third_party/protobuf/CMakeFiles/libprotobuf.dir/build.make:1098: third_party/protobuf/CMakeFiles/libprotobuf.dir/__/src/google/protobuf/util/internal/type_info_test_helper.cc.o] Ошибка 1
c++: fatal error: Убито signal terminated program cc1plus
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [third_party/boringssl-with-bazel/CMakeFiles/ssl.dir/build.make:216: third_party/boringssl-with-bazel/CMakeFiles/ssl.dir/src/ssl/handshake_server.cc.o] Ошибка 1
c++: fatal error: Убито signal terminated program cc1plus
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [third_party/boringssl-with-bazel/CMakeFiles/ssl.dir/build.make:398: third_party/boringssl-with-bazel/CMakeFiles/ssl.dir/src/ssl/ssl_session.cc.o] Ошибка 1
[ 32%] Building C object third_party/boringssl-with-bazel/CMakeFiles/crypto.dir/src/crypto/x509v3/v3_pci.c.o
[ 32%] Building C object third_party/boringssl-with-bazel/CMakeFiles/crypto.dir/src/crypto/pkcs8/p5_pbev2.c.o
[ 32%] Building C object third_party/boringssl-with-bazel/CMakeFiles/crypto.dir/src/crypto/x509v3/v3_conf.c.o
c++: fatal error: Убито signal terminated program cc1plus
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [third_party/boringssl-with-bazel/CMakeFiles/ssl.dir/build.make:286: third_party/boringssl-with-bazel/CMakeFiles/ssl.dir/src/ssl/ssl_asn1.cc.o] Ошибка 1
c++: fatal error: Убито signal terminated program cc1plus
compilation terminated.
[ 32%] Linking C executable bin/acountry
c++: fatal error: Убито signal terminated program cc1plus
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [third_party/boringssl-with-bazel/CMakeFiles/ssl.dir/build.make:552: third_party/boringssl-with-bazel/CMakeFiles/ssl.dir/src/ssl/tls_method.cc.o] Ошибка 1
make[2]: *** [third_party/boringssl-with-bazel/CMakeFiles/ssl.dir/build.make:328: third_party/boringssl-with-bazel/CMakeFiles/ssl.dir/src/ssl/ssl_cipher.cc.o] Ошибка 1
c++: fatal error: Убито signal terminated program cc1plus
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [third_party/boringssl-with-bazel/CMakeFiles/ssl.dir/build.make:188: third_party/boringssl-with-bazel/CMakeFiles/ssl.dir/src/ssl/handshake.cc.o] Ошибка 1
[ 32%] Linking CXX static library libabsl_int128.a
[ 32%] Built target absl_int128
[ 32%] Linking CXX static library libabsl_raw_logging_internal.a
[ 32%] Linking CXX static library libabsl_random_internal_randen.a
[ 32%] Built target absl_raw_logging_internal
[ 32%] Built target absl_random_internal_randen
[ 32%] Building CXX object third_party/abseil-cpp/absl/base/CMakeFiles/absl_base.dir/internal/cycleclock.cc.o
[ 32%] Building CXX object third_party/abseil-cpp/absl/types/CMakeFiles/absl_bad_optional_access.dir/bad_optional_access.cc.o
[ 32%] Building CXX object third_party/abseil-cpp/absl/base/CMakeFiles/absl_throw_delegate.dir/internal/throw_delegate.cc.o
[ 32%] Building CXX object third_party/abseil-cpp/absl/base/CMakeFiles/absl_base.dir/internal/sysinfo.cc.o
[ 32%] Building CXX object third_party/abseil-cpp/absl/debugging/CMakeFiles/absl_debugging_internal.dir/internal/vdso_support.cc.o
[ 32%] Building CXX object third_party/abseil-cpp/absl/debugging/CMakeFiles/absl_debugging_internal.dir/internal/elf_mem_image.cc.o
[ 32%] Building CXX object third_party/abseil-cpp/absl/base/CMakeFiles/absl_base.dir/internal/spinlock.cc.o
[ 33%] Building CXX object third_party/abseil-cpp/absl/debugging/CMakeFiles/absl_debugging_internal.dir/internal/address_is_readable.cc.o
[ 33%] Building CXX object third_party/abseil-cpp/absl/strings/CMakeFiles/absl_strings_internal.dir/internal/ostringstream.cc.o
[ 33%] Building CXX object third_party/abseil-cpp/absl/base/CMakeFiles/absl_base.dir/internal/thread_identity.cc.o
[ 33%] Building CXX object third_party/abseil-cpp/absl/strings/CMakeFiles/absl_strings_internal.dir/internal/utf8.cc.o
[ 33%] Building CXX object third_party/abseil-cpp/absl/base/CMakeFiles/absl_base.dir/internal/unscaledcycleclock.cc.o
[ 33%] Building CXX object third_party/abseil-cpp/absl/strings/CMakeFiles/absl_strings_internal.dir/internal/escaping.cc.o
[ 33%] Building CXX object third_party/abseil-cpp/absl/types/CMakeFiles/absl_bad_variant_access.dir/bad_variant_access.cc.o
[ 33%] Building CXX object third_party/abseil-cpp/absl/base/CMakeFiles/absl_scoped_set_env.dir/internal/scoped_set_env.cc.o
[ 33%] Building CXX object third_party/abseil-cpp/absl/types/CMakeFiles/absl_bad_any_cast_impl.dir/bad_any_cast.cc.o
[ 33%] Built target acountry
[ 33%] Linking CXX static library libabsl_bad_optional_access.a
[ 33%] Built target absl_bad_optional_access
[ 33%] Linking CXX static library libabsl_bad_any_cast_impl.a
[ 33%] Linking CXX static library libtesting.a
[ 33%] Built target absl_bad_any_cast_impl
[ 33%] Linking CXX static library libabsl_throw_delegate.a
[ 33%] Built target testing
[ 33%] Built target absl_throw_delegate
[ 33%] Linking CXX static library libabsl_debugging_internal.a
[ 33%] Linking CXX static library libabsl_bad_variant_access.a
[ 33%] Linking CXX static library libabsl_strings_internal.a
[ 33%] Built target absl_debugging_internal
[ 33%] Built target absl_bad_variant_access
[ 33%] Built target absl_strings_internal
[ 33%] Building CXX object third_party/abseil-cpp/absl/debugging/CMakeFiles/absl_stacktrace.dir/stacktrace.cc.o
[ 33%] Linking CXX static library libabsl_time_zone.a
[ 33%] Linking CXX static library libabsl_scoped_set_env.a
[ 33%] Built target absl_scoped_set_env
[ 33%] Built target absl_time_zone
[ 33%] Linking CXX static library libabsl_base.a
[ 33%] Built target absl_base
[ 33%] Building CXX object third_party/abseil-cpp/absl/base/CMakeFiles/absl_malloc_internal.dir/internal/low_level_alloc.cc.o
[ 33%] Building CXX object third_party/abseil-cpp/absl/strings/CMakeFiles/absl_strings.dir/ascii.cc.o
[ 33%] Building CXX object third_party/abseil-cpp/absl/debugging/CMakeFiles/absl_demangle_internal.dir/internal/demangle.cc.o
[ 33%] Building CXX object third_party/abseil-cpp/absl/strings/CMakeFiles/absl_strings.dir/charconv.cc.o
[ 33%] Building CXX object third_party/abseil-cpp/absl/strings/CMakeFiles/absl_strings.dir/escaping.cc.o
[ 33%] Linking CXX static library libre2.a
[ 33%] Building CXX object third_party/abseil-cpp/absl/strings/CMakeFiles/absl_strings.dir/internal/charconv_bigint.cc.o
[ 33%] Building CXX object third_party/abseil-cpp/absl/strings/CMakeFiles/absl_strings.dir/internal/charconv_parse.cc.o
[ 33%] Building CXX object third_party/abseil-cpp/absl/strings/CMakeFiles/absl_strings.dir/internal/memutil.cc.o
[ 33%] Building CXX object third_party/abseil-cpp/absl/strings/CMakeFiles/absl_strings.dir/numbers.cc.o
[ 33%] Building CXX object third_party/abseil-cpp/absl/strings/CMakeFiles/absl_strings.dir/match.cc.o
[ 33%] Building CXX object third_party/abseil-cpp/absl/strings/CMakeFiles/absl_strings.dir/str_cat.cc.o
[ 33%] Building CXX object third_party/abseil-cpp/absl/strings/CMakeFiles/absl_strings.dir/str_replace.cc.o
[ 33%] Building CXX object third_party/abseil-cpp/absl/strings/CMakeFiles/absl_strings.dir/str_split.cc.o
[ 34%] Building CXX object third_party/abseil-cpp/absl/strings/CMakeFiles/absl_strings.dir/string_view.cc.o
[ 34%] Building CXX object third_party/abseil-cpp/absl/strings/CMakeFiles/absl_strings.dir/substitute.cc.o
[ 34%] Linking CXX static library libabsl_stacktrace.a
[ 34%] Built target absl_stacktrace
[ 34%] Built target re2
[ 34%] Building CXX object third_party/re2/CMakeFiles/random_test.dir/re2/testing/random_test.cc.o
[ 35%] Building CXX object third_party/re2/CMakeFiles/exhaustive_test.dir/re2/testing/exhaustive_test.cc.o
[ 34%] Building CXX object third_party/re2/CMakeFiles/random_test.dir/util/test.cc.o
[ 34%] Building CXX object third_party/re2/CMakeFiles/regexp_benchmark.dir/re2/testing/regexp_benchmark.cc.o
[ 35%] Building CXX object third_party/re2/CMakeFiles/regexp_benchmark.dir/util/benchmark.cc.o
[ 35%] Building CXX object third_party/re2/CMakeFiles/exhaustive_test.dir/util/test.cc.o
[ 35%] Building CXX object third_party/re2/CMakeFiles/exhaustive2_test.dir/util/test.cc.o
[ 35%] Building CXX object third_party/re2/CMakeFiles/exhaustive2_test.dir/re2/testing/exhaustive2_test.cc.o
[ 35%] Building CXX object third_party/re2/CMakeFiles/dfa_test.dir/re2/testing/dfa_test.cc.o
[ 35%] Building CXX object third_party/re2/CMakeFiles/dfa_test.dir/util/test.cc.o
[ 35%] Building CXX object third_party/re2/CMakeFiles/string_generator_test.dir/re2/testing/string_generator_test.cc.o
[ 35%] Building CXX object third_party/re2/CMakeFiles/string_generator_test.dir/util/test.cc.o
[ 35%] Building CXX object third_party/re2/CMakeFiles/exhaustive3_test.dir/re2/testing/exhaustive3_test.cc.o
[ 35%] Building CXX object third_party/re2/CMakeFiles/simplify_test.dir/re2/testing/simplify_test.cc.o
[ 35%] Building CXX object third_party/re2/CMakeFiles/simplify_test.dir/util/test.cc.o
[ 35%] Building CXX object third_party/re2/CMakeFiles/exhaustive1_test.dir/util/test.cc.o
[ 35%] Building CXX object third_party/re2/CMakeFiles/exhaustive3_test.dir/util/test.cc.o
[ 35%] Building CXX object third_party/re2/CMakeFiles/exhaustive1_test.dir/re2/testing/exhaustive1_test.cc.o
[ 35%] Building CXX object third_party/re2/CMakeFiles/compile_test.dir/re2/testing/compile_test.cc.o
[ 35%] Building CXX object third_party/re2/CMakeFiles/charclass_test.dir/re2/testing/charclass_test.cc.o
[ 35%] Building CXX object third_party/re2/CMakeFiles/re2_arg_test.dir/re2/testing/re2_arg_test.cc.o
[ 35%] Building CXX object third_party/re2/CMakeFiles/compile_test.dir/util/test.cc.o
[ 35%] Building CXX object third_party/re2/CMakeFiles/re2_arg_test.dir/util/test.cc.o
[ 35%] Building CXX object third_party/re2/CMakeFiles/charclass_test.dir/util/test.cc.o
[ 35%] Building CXX object third_party/re2/CMakeFiles/filtered_re2_test.dir/re2/testing/filtered_re2_test.cc.o
[ 35%] Building CXX object third_party/re2/CMakeFiles/filtered_re2_test.dir/util/test.cc.o
[ 35%] Building CXX object third_party/re2/CMakeFiles/required_prefix_test.dir/util/test.cc.o
[ 35%] Building CXX object third_party/re2/CMakeFiles/required_prefix_test.dir/re2/testing/required_prefix_test.cc.o
[ 35%] Building CXX object third_party/re2/CMakeFiles/parse_test.dir/re2/testing/parse_test.cc.o
[ 35%] Building CXX object third_party/re2/CMakeFiles/parse_test.dir/util/test.cc.o
[ 35%] Building CXX object third_party/re2/CMakeFiles/re2_test.dir/re2/testing/re2_test.cc.o
[ 35%] Building CXX object third_party/re2/CMakeFiles/re2_test.dir/util/test.cc.o
[ 35%] Building CXX object third_party/re2/CMakeFiles/possible_match_test.dir/re2/testing/possible_match_test.cc.o
[ 35%] Building CXX object third_party/re2/CMakeFiles/mimics_pcre_test.dir/re2/testing/mimics_pcre_test.cc.o
[ 35%] Building CXX object third_party/re2/CMakeFiles/set_test.dir/re2/testing/set_test.cc.o
[ 35%] Linking CXX static library libabsl_demangle_internal.a
[ 35%] Building CXX object third_party/re2/CMakeFiles/set_test.dir/util/test.cc.o
[ 36%] Building CXX object third_party/re2/CMakeFiles/mimics_pcre_test.dir/util/test.cc.o
[ 35%] Building CXX object third_party/re2/CMakeFiles/possible_match_test.dir/util/test.cc.o
[ 35%] Building CXX object third_party/re2/CMakeFiles/regexp_test.dir/re2/testing/regexp_test.cc.o
[ 36%] Building CXX object third_party/re2/CMakeFiles/search_test.dir/re2/testing/search_test.cc.o
[ 36%] Building CXX object third_party/re2/CMakeFiles/search_test.dir/util/test.cc.o
[ 36%] Building CXX object third_party/re2/CMakeFiles/regexp_test.dir/util/test.cc.o
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:4828: third_party/boringssl-with-bazel/CMakeFiles/ssl.dir/all] Ошибка 2
make[1]: *** Ожидание завершения заданий…
[ 36%] Built target absl_demangle_internal
[ 36%] Linking CXX executable mimics_pcre_test
[ 36%] Linking CXX static library libabsl_malloc_internal.a
[ 36%] Linking CXX executable charclass_test
[ 36%] Built target absl_malloc_internal
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:4156: third_party/protobuf/CMakeFiles/libprotobuf-lite.dir/all] Ошибка 2
[ 36%] Linking CXX executable exhaustive1_test
[ 36%] Linking CXX executable simplify_test
[ 36%] Built target mimics_pcre_test
[ 36%] Linking CXX executable parse_test
[ 36%] Linking CXX executable re2_arg_test
[ 36%] Linking CXX executable exhaustive_test
[ 36%] Built target simplify_test
[ 36%] Linking CXX executable random_test
[ 36%] Built target charclass_test
[ 36%] Linking CXX executable set_test
[ 36%] Linking CXX executable string_generator_test
[ 36%] Built target parse_test
[ 36%] Linking CXX executable compile_test
[ 36%] Linking CXX executable required_prefix_test
[ 36%] Linking CXX executable exhaustive2_test
[ 36%] Built target re2_arg_test
[ 36%] Linking CXX static library libabsl_strings.a
[ 36%] Built target exhaustive1_test
[ 36%] Linking CXX executable exhaustive3_test
[ 37%] Linking CXX executable search_test
[ 37%] Built target absl_strings
[ 37%] Linking CXX executable regexp_benchmark
[ 37%] Built target string_generator_test
[ 37%] Built target set_test
[ 37%] Built target random_test
[ 37%] Linking CXX executable regexp_test
[ 37%] Built target exhaustive_test
[ 37%] Linking CXX executable filtered_re2_test
[ 37%] Built target required_prefix_test
[ 37%] Built target compile_test
[ 37%] Built target exhaustive2_test
[ 37%] Linking CXX executable possible_match_test
[ 37%] Built target search_test
[ 37%] Built target regexp_benchmark
[ 37%] Built target regexp_test
[ 37%] Built target filtered_re2_test
[ 37%] Built target exhaustive3_test
[ 37%] Linking CXX executable dfa_test
[ 37%] Linking C static library libcrypto.a
[ 37%] Built target possible_match_test
[ 37%] Built target crypto
[ 37%] Linking CXX executable re2_test
[ 37%] Built target dfa_test
[ 37%] Built target re2_test
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:4104: third_party/protobuf/CMakeFiles/libprotobuf.dir/all] Ошибка 2
make: *** [Makefile:136: all] Ошибка 2
```

dmesg | grep cc1plus

```
[ 5314.651885] [  34968]  1000 34968    16897     2777   155648      169             0 cc1plus
[ 5314.651889] [  35043]  1000 35043    20315     5557   176128      772             0 cc1plus
[ 5314.652370] oom-kill:constraint=CONSTRAINT_NONE,nodemask=(null),cpuset=/,mems_allowed=0,global_oom,task_memcg=/user.slice/user-1000.slice/user@1000.service,task=cc1plus,pid=33509,uid=1000
[ 5314.652376] Out of memory: Killed process 33509 (cc1plus) total-vm:135116kB, anon-rss:65584kB, file-rss:0kB, shmem-rss:0kB, UID:1000 pgtables:280kB oom_score_adj:0
[ 5314.656699] oom_reaper: reaped process 33509 (cc1plus), now anon-rss:0kB, file-rss:0kB, shmem-rss:0kB
[ 5339.579702] [  32609]  1000 32609    27712     7802   233472     5730             0 cc1plus
[ 5339.579703] [  32610]  1000 32610    27916     7594   241664     6333             0 cc1plus
[ 5339.580173] [  34952]  1000 34952    25593    10398   225280      818             0 cc1plus
[ 5339.580177] [  34961]  1000 34961    22454     7432   192512     1020             0 cc1plus
[ 5339.580178] [  34962]  1000 34962    26686    11657   233472     1312             0 cc1plus
[ 5339.580181] [  34968]  1000 34968    16897     2778   155648      170             0 cc1plus
[ 5339.580185] [  35043]  1000 35043    20315     5550   176128      785             0 cc1plus
[ 5339.580690] oom-kill:constraint=CONSTRAINT_NONE,nodemask=(null),cpuset=/,mems_allowed=0,global_oom,task_memcg=/user.slice/user-1000.slice/user@1000.service,task=cc1plus,pid=34126,uid=1000
[ 5339.580697] Out of memory: Killed process 34126 (cc1plus) total-vm:135096kB, anon-rss:72428kB, file-rss:0kB, shmem-rss:0kB, UID:1000 pgtables:284kB oom_score_adj:0
[ 5339.589632] oom_reaper: reaped process 34126 (cc1plus), now anon-rss:0kB, file-rss:0kB, shmem-rss:0kB
[ 5376.740907] [  32609]  1000 32609    27745     7867   237568     5710             0 cc1plus
[ 5376.741369] [  34961]  1000 34961    22966     7501   196608     1021             0 cc1plus
[ 5376.741371] [  34962]  1000 34962    26686    11558   233472     1415             0 cc1plus
[ 5376.741373] [  34968]  1000 34968    18953     4036   172032      174             0 cc1plus
[ 5376.741377] [  35043]  1000 35043    20350     5475   176128      915             0 cc1plus
[ 5376.741818] oom-kill:constraint=CONSTRAINT_NONE,nodemask=(null),cpuset=/,mems_allowed=0,global_oom,task_memcg=/user.slice/user-1000.slice/user@1000.service,task=cc1plus,pid=33083,uid=1000
[ 5376.741825] Out of memory: Killed process 33083 (cc1plus) total-vm:135172kB, anon-rss:56884kB, file-rss:0kB, shmem-rss:0kB, UID:1000 pgtables:280kB oom_score_adj:0
[ 5376.746248] oom_reaper: reaped process 33083 (cc1plus), now anon-rss:0kB, file-rss:0kB, shmem-rss:0kB
```

Comment: Добавьте вывод команды: `dmesg | grep cc1plus` в вопрос.

Comment: @こきん добавил, я убрал какую-то часть, оставил там где "артефакты", тк не влазило

Comment: Ну вот: `Out of memory: Killed process 33509 (cc1plus) total-vm:135116kB, anon-rss:65584kB, file-rss:0kB, shmem-rss:0kB, UID:1000 pgtables:280kB oom_score_adj:0` не хватает памяти.

Comment: Не уверен поможет ли, но попробуйте вместо `make` использовать `ninja` как генератор, и собрать им. Если и это не поможет, то вам нужно будет что-то думать над кол-вом ОЗУ. `cmake "/path/to/build" -GNinja`, после того как проект будет сгенерирован, не запускайте `cmake`, а запустите именно `ninja` из папки в которой вы его генерировали.

Comment: @こきん как именно запускать этот ninja? Я перешел в папку **grpc/cmake/build**, что нужно дальше делать?
Просто не вижу в интернете примера использования ninja

Comment: @こきん я вроде сгенерировал, что нужно дальше делать

```~/CPP_libs/gRPC/grpc/cmake$ ninja -j1```
```[0/1897] Building CXX object CMakeFile...s.dir/src/cpp/common/alts_context.cc.o```

```[1897/1897] Linking C executable third_party/zlib/minigzip64```

Comment: Ну вы вроде бы собрали проект ;)

Comment: @こきん не находит, я наверное что-то ещё не сделал?
CMake Error at client_grpc/CMakeLists.txt:30 (find_package):
  By not providing "FindgRPC.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
  asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "gRPC", but
  CMake did not find one.